# question - compare three variables in xsl and output the differences between the three?

Tags: xslt

I want to use xsl to compare three variables which are created in xsl from txt directory listings. I can do it in bash using diff3 but I have to do this in xsl - not my choice.

example:

$variable1 contains
dog
cat
zebra

$variable2 contains
dog
cat
zebra
donkey

$variable3 contains
dog
cat
zebra
horse

I'd like to have the result of the query show that:

$variable1 was missing donkey, which was present in $variable2, and horse which was present in $variable3

$variable2 was missing horse, which was present in $variable3

$variable3 was missing donkey, which was present in $variable2

Any suggestions? Clearly I am an xsl novice. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using (if you don't know, which processor or environment are you running it in)? Are these variable values a single string with spaces and/or line feeds separating the values, or a sequence of text values? Are you just looking to report the words that are not present, or do you intend to construct the messages that you provided as results?

Answer (score 1):

This **XSLT 2.0** stylesheet demonstrates how you can find which of the words that are in the two other variables, but not in the variable being tested.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="'dog','cat','zebra'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="variable2" select="'dog','cat','zebra','donkey'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="variable3" select="'dog','cat','zebra','horse'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>Variable 1 was missing: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="($variable2, $variable3)[not(. = $variable1)]" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Variable 2 was missing: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="($variable1, $variable3)[not(. = $variable2)]" separator=", "/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Variable 3 was missing: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="($variable1, $variable2)[not(. = $variable3)]" separator=", "/>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces the following output:

```
Variable 1 was missing: donkey, horse
Variable 2 was missing: horse
Variable 3 was missing: donkey
```

You didn't show how the variable values were being assigned. These variables in this stylesheet contain a sequence of string values. If your variables happen to be a single string, you can use functions such as `tokenize()` in order to split the string and return the sequence of words to test.

Comment: thanks that's very helpful! the variables are assigned from tokenized unparsed-text reads of the directory listing txts - which leads to a question - what would the separator be in this case? a space?

Comment: maybe, but might also have carriage returns and/or linefeed characters. You can use `\s+` to tokenize on any of those whitespace characters `tokenize($var, '\s+')`

Comment: thanks, Mads - that is working perfectly for me - to answer my own question above (too late to edit and don't know how to delete comments) the "separator" in the example affects the result output, not the input - so, for example, if you wanted a line break after each result, put in "&#10" instead of ","

Comment: thanks again, Mads - we answered at the same time - re: tokenizing, yes, I used the \s+ option